# Porting loss function written in Tensorflow to Keras results in AttributeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror

I have a loss function written in tensorflow which gets 3 values in `y_in` and 3 values in `y_pred`.

Pseudo-Code for tensorflow-loss:

```
def my_loss(y_in,y_pred):
 with tf.name_scope('loss_scope'): 
    loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(...)
    loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(...)
    loss3 = tf.reduce_mean(...)
 return loss1,loss2,loss3
```

Now I want to use this loss in my keras model, I would simply try it this way:

```
...
out = Dense(3,activation='linear')(con_res)
model = Model(inputs=[In1,In2],output = out)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss=my_loss)
```

Where con_res is the result from the network before. Then with the help of the Dense - Layer it will get reduced to 3 outputs.

The following error occurs:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 910, in compile
>       sample_weight, mask)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 447, in weighted
>       ndim = K.ndim(score_array)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 479, in ndim
>       dims = x.get_shape()._dims
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

The shown traceback occurs after the `.compile` function.

I tried it with a crossentropy loss and it did not throw any error

Comment: my_loss() should return a tensor. not a tuple.

Comment: Thank you, however the losses get calculated by tf.reduce_mean (see edit) - so they should be tensors - or do I have to put them all into one tensor?

Comment: combining the losse with tf.stack did the trick. Do you want to give this as an answer since you lead me into the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function, `my_loss()` should return a tensor. not a tuple.

You can stack the three tensors `(loss1,loss2,loss3)` into a single tensor using
`tf.stack()`.